# Integrating Zuora with GCP Bigquery

Tags: dynamic, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, zuora

I want to setup a Dataflow pipeline to migrate data from Zuora to BigQuery.
what steps should be followed to do so? I am very new to Zuora.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Zuora has an [API](https://developer.zuora.com/api-references/quickstart-api/tag/Introduction/) , you can easily implement something that will read data from the API, do any kind of transform, and write to a BigQuery table using the [BigQueryIO connector](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/)